# Antd design pro table - button query is not working

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I click to button query in antd design table pro
but not working

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a specific function to it?
By default, clicking the query button will trigger the synToUrl method, it chains search values into params of the current URL as below:

```
<ProTable<any>
        form={{
          syncToUrl: (values, type) => {
            if (type === "get") {
              return {
                ...values,
              };
            }
            return values;
          },
        }}
```

If you want to make further action, you should create base on that util.

Please provide image or code to make thing clearer. Vậy nha bro!